# How is the conjugation of gustar determined in "Nos gusta ir al cine"?

Tags: gramática, verbos, conjugación

In

> Nos gusta ir al cine.

nos is plural, why the verb gustar should take the

"3rd-person singular present indicative conjugation"

gusta? Shouldn't it be

"1st-person plural present (?) nominative (?) conjugation"

gustamos?

Comment: Go look up the verb gustar in Spanish. It is structured like this: Apples are pleasing to me. Me gustan las manzanas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subject in:

- Nos gusta ir al cine

is the infinitival "ir al cine", which is third person singular. For you to understand it better, we can rephrase the sentence following the less natural order below:

- Ir al cine nos gusta (Going to the cinema appeals to us).

While "like" in English takes as a subject the person who likes, "gustar" in Spanish takes as a subject the thing or person that arouses somebody's sense of liking.

Comment: Is there an online tool that can do sentence analysis to segment different functional parts of the sentence and for each explain some basic properties, much similar to your answer?

Comment: So, the the original sentence's structure is <object> + <verb: gustar> + <subject>?

Comment: Exactly. This is a very usual order with the verb "gustar". A possible reason for this might be that the subject tends to be longer than the predicate, and thus calls for its posposition. For example: Me gusta ir al cine con mis amigos, is much more balanced and natural than: Ir al cine con mis amigos me gusta.